# Tunnel is up but cannot ping directly connected network

Tags: cisco-vpn, site-to-site-vpn

We configured a site-to-site VPN and here is the topology. I control the network on the left but not the one on the right. All devices in our network has public IPs.

Server---ASA5505---Cisco887======Internet=====ASA5510---devices

I can see the tunnel is up and can do extended ping using a loopback interface. From the 10.175 and 10.165 networks, they can also ping my loopback address. I can also dial in using a Cisco VPN client, and can connect to the devices on the right.

```
#show crypto session
Crypto session current status

Interface: Vlan3
Profile: xxx-profile
Session status: UP-ACTIVE     
Peer: 213.121.x.x port 500 
   IKEv1 SA: local 77.245.x.x/500 remote 213.121.x.x/500 Active 
   IPSEC FLOW: permit ip 10.0.20.0/255.255.255.240 10.175.0.0/255.255.128.0 
        Active SAs: 0, origin: crypto map
   IPSEC FLOW: permit ip 10.0.20.0/255.255.255.240 10.165.0.0/255.255.192.0 
        Active SAs: 2, origin: crypto map

#ping 10.165.29.39 source loopback 2
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.165.29.39, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 10.0.20.1 
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 16/17/20 ms
```

My problem is the devices on the right cannot reach my server. They could only ping the loopback address and nothing else.

I'm pasting some diagnostics related to routing thinking perhaps routing is my issue. I can paste all the running-config on my side of network if needed.

```
#show ip int brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
ATM0                       unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Ethernet0                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
FastEthernet0              unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      connected to ASA    
FastEthernet1              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
FastEthernet2              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
FastEthernet3              unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Loopback1                  10.0.20.65      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Loopback2                  10.0.20.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Virtual-Template1          77.245.x.x      YES unset  up                    down    
Virtual-Template2          77.245.x.x      YES unset  up                    down    
Vlan1                      unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
Vlan3                      77.245.x.x      YES NVRAM  up                    up      connected to the Internet

#show run | section ip route
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 77.245.x.x
ip route 213.121.240.36 255.255.255.255 Vlan3

#show access-list
Extended IP access list 102
    10 permit ip 10.0.20.0 0.0.0.15 10.175.0.0 0.0.127.255 (3332 matches)
    20 permit ip 10.0.20.0 0.0.0.15 10.165.0.0 0.0.63.255 (3498 matches)

#show vlan-switch

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    
3    VLAN0003                         active    Fa0, Fa1, Fa2, Fa3
1002 fddi-default                     act/unsup 
1003 token-ring-default               act/unsup 
1004 fddinet-default                  act/unsup 
1005 trnet-default                    act/unsup

#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is 77.245.x.x to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 77.245.x.x
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 3 masks
C        10.0.20.0/28 is directly connected, Loopback2
L        10.0.20.1/32 is directly connected, Loopback2
C        10.0.20.64/28 is directly connected, Loopback1
L        10.0.20.65/32 is directly connected, Loopback1
S        10.165.0.0/18 [1/0] via 213.121.x.x
      77.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
S        77.0.0.0/8 [1/0] via 77.245.x.x
C        77.245.x.x/29 is directly connected, Vlan3
L        77.245.x.x/32 is directly connected, Vlan3
      213.121.x.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
S        213.121.x.x is directly connected, Vlan3
```

I read some of the posts here which lead to NATing issue but I'not sure of my next step. Should I translate my public address to private and route it to the loopback address? (only guessing)

[CISCO VPN site to site](https://serverfault.com/questions/450453/cisco-vpn-site-to-site)

[Site-to-Site VPN between two ASA 5505s only working in one direction](https://serverfault.com/questions/396593/site-to-site-vpn-between-two-asa-5505s-only-working-in-one-direction?rq=1)

Hope someone could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd give packet-tracer on the ASA a try, it's previously at least helped me pinpoint where things are going wrong. I.e. you could run packet-tracer on the combination of icmp/ping that's failing and see what decision your ASA made for it. (And, it's not entirely unlikely that your problem is NAT. If you do NAT of your hosts going out, you'll explicitly have to exempt tunnel traffic from NAT).